# Java reflection. Convert returned value to double

Tags: java, reflection

I want to use Java reflection to convert the returned value of a method to a double, regardless of whether the actual return type is a Number or a primitive int, long, float, double, etc.

To ensure that the method is actually returning a value that I can convert to a double, I am using

```
List<String> numberTypes = Arrays.asList("int", "Integer", "double", "Double", "long", "Long", "float", "Float");
if (numberTypes.contains(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName())){
    Double a = new Double( method.invoke(obj) );
}
```

But Eclipse tells me here that it wants me to case the output of `invoke` to a `Double`. Essentially it wants me to do this...

```
if (numberTypes.contains(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName())){
    Double a = new Double( (Double) method.invoke(obj) );
}
```

But that seems to me like I could be introducing an error because if the object is actually a primitive int (for instance), then it seems to me like the cast would be incorrect. So the open questions:

1) Should I just insert the cast?

2) Is there a better way of converting the return value to a Double?

3) If the ultimate goal is to then convert the Double to a String, is there a shortcut I can take here? For instance, it might turn out that we ultimately just need to send the value as a String over the network. Is there a better way to accomplish the above if that is the ultimate goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Java uses compile-time polymorphism for overloading - which overloaded method to run is determined during compilation.

For example:

```
static double f(Integer x) { ... }
static double f(Double x) { ... }

// somewhere in the code:
Object h = new Double(14.0);
f(h); // won't compile - unable to determine which method you want to invoke
f((Integer)h); // will compile, but fail at run-time with ClassCastException
f((Double)h); // will compile and succeed.
```

That's why Eclipse tells you to perform a cast - it needs to know which exact constructor to invoke (`Double` has two constructors - one accepts `String`, another one - `double`).

Now I think it should be clear that you can't simply cast to `Double` (as you may have value of other type), so you shouldn't just insert the cast.

2). Reflection [automatically boxes primitives for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764588/reflection-on-methods-with-a-primitive-numeric-return-type). So there is a better way to accomplish this:

```
double a = ((Number)method.invoke(obj)).doubleValue();
```

3). Considering that you, most likely, want to format your value in some way, I think you shouldn't take any shortcuts.