# Argument is not assignable to 'int'

Tags: java, android, reflection, process

I'm trying to convert a code to reflection. This is the exact code that I'm trying to convert to reflection

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Here is my reflection code.

```
Class<?> process = Class.forName("android.os.Process");
Method killProcess = process.getMethod("killProcess", Integer.TYPE);
Method myPid = process.getMethod("myPid");
killProcess.invoke(null, myPid.invoke(null));
```

How ever the issue is I'm getting an warning on this line `myPid.invoke(null)` the warning as stated in the title is `Argument is not assignable to 'int'`

Here is a snapshot of the warning.

My question is how do I resolve this warning without using surpass? I wan't to resolve this a proper way instead of using surpass warning annotation or disabling the warning.

[image]

Comment: Correct, but your method expects a more specific type. But since your snippet is very limited, I've deleted the old comment.

Comment: Also you can declare local int variable, save there `myPid.invoke(null)` result and transmit it to killProcess.invoke method call

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764588/reflection-on-methods-with-a-primitive-numeric-return-type

Comment: @Hulk Look at my answer, I don't see how they are related? can you directly link the answer?

Comment: It is related in that it also discusses how primitive types are wrapped when returned by `Method.invoke()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casing the `invoke` return value from `myPid` resolved the warning.

```
killProcess.invoke(null, (int) myPid.invoke(null));
```

Full code snippet after casting it to `int`

```
Class<?> process = Class.forName("android.os.Process");
Method killProcess = process.getMethod("killProcess", Integer.TYPE);
Method myPid = process.getMethod("myPid");
killProcess.invoke(null, (int) myPid.invoke(null));
```

Snapshot of code snippet after casting it to `int`

[image]